# Is there a set of arguments for ps which show Java processes more clearly?

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, process, ps

When running the `ps` command I get an output like this:

```
[nick]$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3287 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
12308 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
19544 pts/3    00:00:00 STS
19548 pts/3    00:45:25 java
19753 pts/3    00:04:10 java
21149 pts/3    00:15:25 java
```

This doesn't help me that much because I don't know what each Java process really is.  Running `ps T` gives more information, but now there's too much!

```
[nick]$ ps T
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3287 pts/3    Ss     0:00 bash
12319 pts/3    R+     0:00 ps T
19544 pts/3    S      0:00 /home/nick/springsource/sts-3.0.0.RELEASE/STS
19548 pts/3    Sl    45:25 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5 -Xms256m -Xmx1536m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -jar /home/nick/springsource/sts-3.0.0.RELEASE//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar -os linux -w......
19753 pts/3    Sl     4:10 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:48135 -Dcatalina.base=/home/nick/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp3 -Dcatalina.home=/home/nic......
21149 pts/3    Sl    15:25 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:57346 -Dcatalina.base=/home/nick/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp5 -Dcatalina.home=/home/nic......
```

Is there a way of just displaying the filename of the Java package or class being run?  Something like this:

```
[nick]$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3287 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
12308 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
19544 pts/3    00:00:00 STS
19548 pts/3    00:45:25 java abc.jar
19753 pts/3    00:04:10 java def.java
21149 pts/3    00:15:25 java ghi.jar
```

If this can't be done with `ps` arguments, is there a way of achieving it with `grep`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably `jps` cli utility or graphical `jconsole`.

Comment: jps looks good, however it doesn't show any non-Java processes.  Ideally I was looking for something that shows everything.

Answer (score 4):

No, not with ps. It's either all args or none (modulo truncation of the arglist). But what about filtering the long ps output to leave just what you want? There's a lot you can do with sed, awk, perl, cut and others. The manuals have all the details.

Example: To print fields 1 through 4 and the last field, use

```
ps T | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $NF}'
```

Note how this matches the Unix philosophy of having one tool do one thing well: ps prints process information, while awk picks the fields you want.